# Question suggestion for Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2021: Are certifications valuable?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2021

I have a question pair suggestion for Stack Overflow Developer survey 2021.

> Do you think certifications are important for getting hired?
>
> a) Highly Agree
> b) Somewhat agree
> c) Neutral
> d) Somewhat disagree
> e) Highly disagree

and

> While hiring someone or if I were to hire someone, I would take certifications attained by the candidate seriously.
>
> a) Highly Agree
> b) Somewhat agree
> c) Neutral
> d) Somewhat disagree
> e) Highly disagree

I think both these questions should be asked together in unison, because I think, there will be many programmers who are just "going with system". They have achieved many certifications because their jobs require them to do so, but they themselves do not see the value in them.

Thoughts?

Comment: The first one might provide some interesting data but not the second one.

Comment: Majority of developers are not directly responsible for hiring. Second one seems out of scope

Comment: That's curious, @Dave. I would have expressed precisely the *opposite* opinion about the relative usefulness of these questions. Can you explain more why you think the second one is of limited value? I would rather know what someone on the hiring side is expecting, rather than whatever (mis-)information that job seekers are operating under.

Comment: Good question @CodyGray. I made the comment on the assumption, possibly incorrect, that a significant portion of the users of this family of sites are NOT in a hiring position. Upon reflection the 2nd question could be of benefit but I think it would require a not applicable option for those who aren't in a hiring position.

Comment: Although they might not be in a hiring position at the time of giving the answer, it gives insight about their opinion about the subject. We can reword it like, "If I were to hire someone, I would take certifications seriously"

Comment: On this topic I would love to also see: `While hiring someone, An active GitHub profile by the candidate scores extra points.` I do interviews and when I see a github link in a resume I dive into the profile to see what they are doing and is always a nice way to start the conversation